# prin1: is it possible to have a progress reporter?

Tags: print

My undo-tree history for a fair amount of editing is over 30 seconds when exporting to a string, and I'd like to see a progress reporter if that is possible.  Assuming we have `(prin1 OBJECT (current-buffer))`, is a progress reporter possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `make-progress-reporter` and related functions, in `subr.el`, to see if they correspond to what you're looking for.

See the Elisp manual, node [Progress](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Progress.html).

(Of course, this is not built into `prin1`.  You would need to wrap `prin1` or whatever in your own function that uses a progress reporter.  If you think that `prin1` is not essential to your question, please consider removing it from the question title.)